# Is it safe to run the C preprocessor several times on the same source?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

From my experience, the C preprocessor just behaves as no-op when running on a previously preprocessed source. But is this behaviour guaranteed by the standard? Or maybe an implementation could have a preprocessor that modifies previously preprocessed code and for example removes/modifies line directives, or performs other modifications that could confuse the compiler?

Comment: How are you invoking the pre-processor, exactly? It's usually part of the compiler and you can't run it by itself manually. Also, a file that goes through the C preprocessor does not overwrite itself.

Comment: I mean multiple invocation of the preprocessor. For example `cpp src.c > prepro.c` and then `cpp prepro.c > prepro2.c`

Comment: The preprocessor only modifies its output (relative to its input) in response to a preprocessor-directive; the compiler (which receives the preprocessor's output) won't know how to handle any preprocessor-directives, so presumably the output of the preprocessor can never have any preprocessor-directives still in it (if we expect the compiler to be able to use the code).  Therefore I think it is effectively guaranteed that running already-preprocessed code through the preprocessor will be a no-op, even if it isn't stated as such in the C standard.

Comment: Your example in the comment above would simply produce two copies of the same identical file. It's the command line equivalent of `copy test.txt test1.txt copy test.txt test2.txt`. A binary comparison of the two files contents would be the exact same, as would the two files in your example.

Comment: Some clang devs seem to think doing so should be allowed to silence some warnings or generate new ones: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39367#c1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, preprocessing via `cpp` is not guaranteed to be idempotent (a noop after the first run). A simple counterexample:

```
#define X #define Y z
X
Y
```

The first invocation will yield:

```
 #define Y z
Y
```

The second one:

```
z
```

Having said that, valid C code shouldn't be doing something like that (because the output wouldn't be valid input for next stages of the compiler).

Moreover, depending on what you are trying to do, `cpp` has options like `-fpreprocessed` that may help.

Comment: Cop is not a c compiler.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland OP commented that he/she was using `cpp`.

Comment: I think you mean that it's not guaranteed to be *idempotent*. It's not guaranteed to be a no-op either, of course, since it's expected that the preprocessor will, in fact, do something (unless the source has no preprocessor directives or mandatory macros). But that's not surprising

Comment: @rici That's the proper term, yep. I was trying to use OP's own words. Thanks!

Comment: I think there are far more "practical" answers where this doesn't work. One obvious problem is predefined macros; you'd need to be able to turn them all off entirely in order to feed the preprocessed source back in, or any instance of them in the preprocessor output would get double-expanded. I recall seeing/making even better examples but can't think of them right now.

Comment: This feels like something that should be Turing-complete, so repeated applications could carry out arbitrary calculations...

Comment: What about the `#line` directives created by the preprocessor? Do you think there could exist a preprocessor that removes them if the input was already preprocessed? (IMHO a preprocessor would be severely broken if it does that, but I'm asking just in case you know such a risk exists in some implementation)

Comment: @cess The preprocessor does not know if the input has been already preprocessed or not. Anyway, it depends on your preprocessor and how you tell it to proceed. GNU `cpp` has quite a few options that allow you to tweak the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The standard does not define a "preprocessor" as a separate component. The closest it comes is in the description of phase 4 of the translation process in §5.1.1.2:

> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded, and
>    `_Pragma` unary operator expressions are executed. If a character sequence that
>    matches the syntax of a universal character name is produced by token
>    concatenation (6.10.3.3), the behavior is undefined. A `#include` preprocessing
>    directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1
>    through phase 4, recursively. All preprocessing directives are then deleted.

However, the translation phases defined in that section are not separable, nor are they guaranteed to be independent of each other:

> Implementations shall behave as if these separate phases occur, even though many are typically folded together in practice. Source files, translation units, and translated translation units need not necessarily be stored as files, nor need there be any one-to-one correspondence between these entities and any external representation. The description is conceptual only, and does not specify any
> particular implementation. *(Footnote 6 from the same section.)*

So there is no contemplated mechanism to extract the result of translation phases 1-4 in any form, much less as a text file -- in fact, if the translation phases were implemented precisely as described, the output of phase 4 would be a sequence of tokens -- and neither is there a mechanism to feed that output back into the translator.

In other words, you might have some tool which calls itself a preprocessor, and it might even be part of a compiler suite. But that tool's behaviour is outside of the scope of the C standard. So there are no guarantees at all from the standard.

By the way, if the token stream which comes out of phase 4 were naively converted to text, it might not correctly preserve token boundaries. Most preprocessor tools inject extra whitespace at points where this would otherwise occur. That allows the output of the tool to be fed into a compiler, at least in most cases. (See [@acorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65045724/1566221) for an example where this wouldn't work correctly.) But this behaviour is neither required nor regulated by the standard, either.